# Question mark on special chars

Tags: encoding

Yesterday i was working on a file when notepad++ crashed. I then went in the backup folder of the program to restore the file. After the restoration, special chars (such as `€` or accented letters) are displayed as a question mark in a black diamod. What is strange is that this happen only in this page, the other pages in the whole WP are displayed correctly! I trashed the file and wrote a new file with the same name and the same shortcode but the problem persist! How can i fix this?

Comment: Make sure the file is encoded in UTF-8 without a BOM.

Comment: Ok, it seems that when Notepad++ crashed, it automatically set itself by default on ANSI and so, every single file that i was creating since the crash was wrongly encoded. Thanks toscho for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress sends all HTML content encoded as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). If you save a file in a single-byte encoding, like Windows-1252¹, you create invalid characters for UTF-8. These are displayed with a replacement character, usually (but not necessary) as a question mark in a black diamond.

Always use UTF-8 for everything. Do not use a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order mark), because this is treated as a printable character by PHP, and you will get the famous *Headers already sent* error.

¹ **ANSI** is [not a real encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#ANSI_code_page). It resolves to your operating system’s locale encoding. This term should be forbidden in all text editors.